# In what circumstances should I use fixed width integer for enum class in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

In what circumstances should I use this:

```
enum class MyFixedType : uint32_t // or any other fixed width integer type
{
    ID1,
    ID2,
    ID3
};
```

over this:

```
enum class MyType
{
    ID1,
    ID2,
    ID3
};
```

?

Comment: when you need an enum of certain size

Comment: @BЈовић: why would one care about its size? when?

Comment: @Nawaz When optimizing memory footprint, for alignment reasons, etc.

Comment: @Nawaz: You can't think of examples where you would need to optimize a program's memory footprint? Okay. You're working on a system where memory is more limited than usual.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Even then, you'd use `enum class MyFixedType : char` or `enum class MyFixedType : unsigned char`.  It's hard enough to find a context where you'd use `uint32_t` to begin with; I can't imagine any case where you'd use it to type an enum.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Agreed. But you might use `uint16_t` if your have more than 256 enum values, which is not entirely unrealistic.

Comment: I sometimes use uint16_t for flag enums that need to be stored in uint16_t fields for network transfer. I think once a coworker tried to add another flag and was told by the compiler that it wont fit.

Comment: There is this whole world of embedded systems development.

Comment: Think about some `uint32_t` field that you need to write somewhere which you want to map to an enum. Either you have to cast the enum or you set its size to `uint32_t` in the first place. I'd prefer the second solution.

Comment: @jasal That was the case I was considering as well. Memory, etc, never entered my mind until I saw the comments above.

Comment: Another example: Your architecture aligns at 4 byte boundaries. You have an array of enum values. It will be more efficient to manipulate the individual items when you use an enum with a size of 32 bits.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: No I cannot. I cannot imagine a situation where my enums consumes memory *so* much that I need to take of this as well.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'd use `short` or `unsigned short`, rather than `uint16_t` for this.

Comment: @JamesKanze: why? the data type used in the serializer is uint16_t, so why not match it? what if one day short is a different size? or you do this with int/uint32_t and their size is different one day on a new platform?

Comment: @jasal You have to go through exactly the same steps to read or write a `uint32_t` as you have to go through to write an untyped enum.  The protocol specifies a certain format, and you have to convert the enum to that format.

Comment: @jasal With regards to optimization: `uint32_t` is a typedef, not a basic type (and it might not even be present).  For optimization purposes, if compilers are following the expressed intent of the standard, you should use `int`.

Comment: @Nawaz I can.  If you have a large arrays of them.  (Even if they fit, putting them in a short can improve locality, and thus run time.)  But as I said, the answer to that would be `unsigned short`, not `uint16_t`.  Or maybe `uint_least16_t` or something like that.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Compatibility with poorly designed legacy software _could_ be a reason.  But in practice, I can't think of any good reason why serialization software would use `uint16_t`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I disagree. You should definitely __not__ use `int` when writing portable code for embedded environments. The standard does not specify its size exactly, only a minimum range.

Comment: @jasal Embedded environments are a bit special; code for them is never portable, and you should use whatever your compiler documentation says to use.  Which at least in the embedded environments I've worked in was `int`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The best reason I can think of to use uint16_t in a serialization format is that the serialization format specifies to have an unsigned integer of the length of 16 bit. But maybe thats not good enough of a reason for everyone

Comment: @PlasmaHH Serialization formats are almost always specified in terms of bytes, and all of the input and output takes place in bytes (at least on the network and under Unix).  An `uint16_t` has to be formatted, just as you would format an `unsigned short`; the difference is that the latter is more portable, and also more descriptive of what you have to do.

Comment: @JamesKanze: wait, you say that "an unsigned integer with at least 16 bits" is more descriptive than "an unsigned integer with exactly 16 bits"?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm saying that it corresponds more to the reality.  And makes the code more portable.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It is funny that of the ~60 network protocols I implemented in the last decade the majority uses descriptions like "16 bit unsigned integer" and typedefs/abbreviations like uint16 for them. The rest of the protocols that don't do are ASCII and FAST based encodings... It looks like what is "normal" and "corresponds to reality" is very dependent on the field you are working with

Comment: @PlasmaHH At a higher level.  They all also define in some way how to convert the 16 bits to bytes (or in some cases, even bits).  When implementing the protocol, the values for those 16 bit integers will typically be `int`, which will be formatted to and from the 2 bytes the protocol demands, according to the rules of conversion specified by the protocol.  (The internet protocols, for example, require 2's complement, with the upper 8 bits first, then the lower 8 bits.  If your `int`s are 2's complement, all you need is a bit of shifting and masking.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: you would be surprised how many don't define that, or have an introductionary "all values are little endian" and I have never seen any not implicitly assuming 2nds complement. And a whole lot of them just say "here is a bunch of structs, memcpy them on/from the network"

Comment: @PlasmaHH "memcpy them on/from the network" doesn't work; I've seen byte order change from one version of the compiler to the next.  As for 2's complement, Google's protocol buffers aren't (but then, they don't have any 16 bit int type either); as for the others, I've never seen one which didn't specify byte order, and explicitly specify 2's complement.  All of the Internet protocols are very precise about this.

Comment: @JamesKanze: regardles of whether this works or not (and btw. for me and my environment it always did), they are specifying their protocol in that way.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Who specifies protocols that way?  Certainly not the IETF.  Nor any of the ISO standards I've seen.

Comment: @JamesKanze: NYSE, NASDAQ, Leica, Siemens, Airbus, just to name a few I had contact with. Lots of Banks, Stock exchanges and manufacturers of industrial equipment.  The majority of protocols "out there" isn't some (open) international standard, but some proprietary stuff. Yet the majority of communications is using some "open" standards. Fun addition: often in structs, their "native" compilers padding is expressed in char arrays of given length, often called like "char filler_2[2];" or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few scenario's out of the top of my head where it could be useful:

1. There is limited space and you really don't need the standard int-sized enums. If you are on a system where integers are stored in 64bit format and you only have less the 255 different enum values, you might need to specify that you want/need less bits per enum-element.
2. Efficient communication between machines. Assuming you know that on both machines the same byte order is used, but integers have a different default size, it might be more efficient to have a fixed width enum, as you can then communicate some bits, instead of a serialised message.
3. You might have an important order in you enum and you might want that when you add two enums with an operator+ that when you add 2 elements, the resulting element is never between your 2 elements (which could happen when a part of you enum-values is negative, like it is in the standard implementation).

I'd guess most of these are only important in embedded cases. For example, when you need to implement a program for a microwave oven or even for the chip on your credit card, places where you haven't got a few GB of memory, but rather a few bytes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. It seems indeed that it may be useful in some particular cases. Very instructive, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the greatest use of enums is code clarity.

Lets assume we have a custom 32-bit hardware device, which has 3 registers :

- 8-bit register to read and write id
- 8-bit register to read and write status
- 32-bit register to read and write color

One implementation might be this :

```
#include <iostream>

struct SomeDeviceMemoryMap1
{
    unsigned int  id : 8;
    unsigned int  status : 8;
    unsigned int  reserved : 16;
    unsigned int  color : 32;
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(SomeDeviceMemoryMap1)<<std::endl;

    SomeDeviceMemoryMap1 m1;
    m1.id = 1;
    m1.status = 5;
    m1.color = 33;
}
```

In c++03, if you used enum, it would be converted into an integer type.

c++11 introduced a way to set the size of an enum. The above example can be converted into this :

```
#include <iostream>

enum class MyFixedType1 : uint8_t
{
    ID1=0,
    ID2,
    ID3
};

enum class MyFixedType2 : uint8_t
{
    STATUS1,
    STATUS2,
    STATUS3=5
};

enum class MyFixedType3 : uint32_t
{
    RED,
    BLUE = 33,
    BLACK
};

struct SomeDeviceMemoryMap2
{
    MyFixedType1  id;
    MyFixedType2  status;
    unsigned int  reserved : 16;
    MyFixedType3  color;
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(SomeDeviceMemoryMap2)<<std::endl;

    SomeDeviceMemoryMap2 m2;
    m2.id = MyFixedType1::ID1;
    m2.status = MyFixedType2::STATUS3;
    m2.color = MyFixedType3::BLUE;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. "Lets assume we have a custom 32-bit hardware device, which has 3 registers [...] ": can you name such device please?

Comment: @Korchkidu No, that was just an example.

Comment: ok, thanks. While theory is great too, I am really interested in practical examples though. Because this is code I read and I just wanted to be sure that in our case, it was useless. Most probably it is then. Thanks again!

Comment: @Korchkidu You didn't say what your case really is. Maybe in your case it is useless as you say